# Ruby eval without round

Tags: ruby

I have a sanitised string I want to evaluate using ruby eval. The string may contain any simple arithmetic formula, like '44/5'.

The problem is that the result of `eval('44/5')` will be 8 (instead of 8.8).

It happens as a part of evaluating (because `1.0*eval('44/5')` gives 8.0).

I didn't find any extra parameter for eval to manage it.

I even tried to prepend or wrap the string to convert it to:

```
'0.0+44/5'
```

or

```
'1.0*(44/5)'
```

But it still doesn't give me 8.8.

`eval('44.0/5')` gives me the desired result but I don't want to insert anything inside the string (I am ready just to wrap it if necessary).

Any idea how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use [`mathn` from Ruby's core library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/Math.html):

```
require 'mathn'

res = eval('44/5')      #=> (44/5)
res.to_f                #=> 8.8
```

This library will automatically convert to rationals where appropriate.

Comment: this is brilliant +1 for the knowledge think this needs to be added to the ruby documentation

Comment: @bjhaid It is in the docs ;-) I've linked to it.

Comment: the docs does not explain that you get a Rational object (the object type), its not straightforward for some beings, had to just check pry/irb to know that it was a rational object

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. Yes that'd be a good idea.

Comment: Requiring the mathn may effect other parts of the code (imagine that the eval code is just a small method of a class in a huge system) because it changes the behaviour Fixnum and Bignum (look at http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/25644). I would like to have a way to isolate it (something like mixin mathn into my module). Any tested solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: That's a general problem with how monkey patches are handled in Ruby. This needs to be implemented in the programming language itself before we can do such things. [Ruby 2.0 introduces refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) as an experimental feature to solve this problem, with the effect that monkeypatches can be applied to a single file instead of your whole ecosystem. Unfortunately, the MathN library would have to be rewritten to actually use refinements instead of just monkey patching the builtin classes.

Comment: There is no official implementation of MathN with refinements yet, but I have put one together for you in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/padde/8184747. Note that you will get warnings because refinements are still an experimental feature.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is using [**`Rational#to_f`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Rational.html#method-i-to_f):

```
Rational('44/5').to_f # => 8.8
'44/5'.to_r.to_f # => 8.8
```

Comment: String has a `to_r`method: '44/5'.to_r

Comment: @steenslag Yes.. `'44/5'.to_r # => (44/5)`, but after that `#to_f` needs to be called. Anyway I have added that also.. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really help in my case (as I told the string can represent any arithmetic formula, for example '2+3/4')

Comment: @Alexander I don't get you. And how the accepted answer differs from this one? Reading at your question what I can see is - your problem was - you are getting 8, whereas you are looking for 8.8.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find any extra parameter for eval to manage it.

Because `eval` is for all things, not only mathematicall equations.

Arup's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733581/2597260) looks nicer but here is mine:

```
str = '4/5'
eval('1.0*'+ str) #0.8
```

ps. 2nd string (`1.0*(44/5)`) won't work because `(44/5)` is evaluated first(8 = integer) and then you multiply by `1.0`(= 8.0).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why no one has mentioned that to force a float put a float in the divisor. i.e.

```
eval('44/5') 
#=> 8
eval('44/5.0')
#=> 8.8
```

Although if you lack control over the string it might be more difficult but this would work

```
eval('44/5'.split("/").map(&:to_f).join("/"))
#=> 8.8
```

to handle multiple arthimitic symbols using eval

```
 pattern = /([0-9]\.?[0-9]+|[0-9]+|[+-\/*\(\)])/
 str = "2+3/4"
 str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}
 #=> [2.0,"+",3.0,"/",4.0]
 str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}.join
 #=> "2.0+3.0/4.0"
 eval(str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}.join)
 #=> 2.75
```

Works with parentheses too and existing floats

```
 str = "(2+3)/4"
 eval(str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}.join)
 #=> 1.25

 str = "(2.3+1)/4"
 eval(str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}.join)
 #=> 0.825
```

Issue with Rational method

```
 str = "(2.3+3)/4*2"
 str.to_r.to_f
 #=>0.0
 eval(str.scan(pattern).flatten.map{|e| e =~(/[0-9]/) ? e.to_f : e}.join)
 #=> 2.65
```

Very simple without additional libraries.